# How can I sort by category in wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Here's my code:

[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="summer_camp" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More"]

Answer (score 0):

You can set this properties for sorting, hope this will help you,

```
[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="summer_camp" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More" category="category_slug" orderby="title" order="DESC"]
```

- category  A comma separated list of categories to include by slug. Default = null
- order     Order posts ASC(ascending) or DESC(descending) order. Default = 'DESC'
- orderby   Order posts by date, title, name, menu order, author, post ID or comment count. Default = 'date'